# Django nani and model inheritance

Tags: django, inheritance, django-models

I use Django nani http://readthedocs.org/docs/django-nani/en/latest/ and want to define two models (one inherits another):

```
class ItemBase(TranslatableModel):
    translations = TranslatedFields(
        name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    )
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=40)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    worth = models.PositiveIntegerField()

class EquipBase(ItemBase):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EquipBase, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    level = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
```

However, I do get the following error when using syncdb.

`django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: No TranslatedFields found on <class 'main.world.items.models.EquipBase'>, subclasses of TranslatableModel must define TranslatedFields.`

What's the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the "**translations**" to the EquipBase insted of ItemBase and use models.Model as super class for ItemBase:

```
class ItemBase(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=40)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    worth = models.PositiveIntegerField()



class EquipBase(ItemBase):
    translations = TranslatedFields(
        name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EquipBase, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    level = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
```